# Rated model of driving-related processes and objects

Tags: perception, reference-request, vision, attention

The Salience, Effort, Effort and Value (SEEV) model for predicting the distribution of visual attention contains a parameter called 'value' which represents the importance of a certain area of the field of view concerning a given task context.

Does anyone know a project or study that actually did a 'value model' for the traffic context?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A 2006 study by [Horrey, Wickens and Consalus](http://www.researchgate.net/profile/Christopher_Wickens/publication/6981582_Modeling_drivers'_visual_attention_allocation_while_interacting_with_in-vehicle_technologies/links/00b49518150af39a95000000.pdf) implemented a computational SEEV (Salience, Effort, Effort, Value) model for driving behavior that predicted scanning behavior, which I surmise is what was meant. The authors conclude:

> The most important practical implication of the current results is
>   that a simple expected value version of the SEEV model provides
>   a plausible and effective predictive model of scanning in driving.

This seems to fit your request.

**References**

- Horrey, W. J., Wickens, C. D., & Consalus, K. P. (2006). Modeling drivers' visual attention allocation while interacting with in-vehicle technologies. Journal of Experimental Psychology: Applied, 12(2), 67.